# How to automount with a chroot?

Tags: 16.04, mount, fstab, automount, chroot

So in a chroot I have a /etc/fstab file. If I run `mount -a` in the chroot, it mounts the partitions listed. However, even when using the `auto` option, they do not mount when entering the chroot.

What is the best way to get automounting to work with a chroot? I know one way would be to just put `mount -a` in some startup file, but it would be better if worked similarly to an actual environment. (In particular, one of the mount points is `/usr`, so I'm afraid it will not work correctly unless it happens early enough in the start up process.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing: there is actually no *startup process* in a chroot.

When you run something like, say, `chroot /newroot /bin/sh`, what happens is [almost the same as running `/newroot/bin/sh` normally](https://www.maizure.org/projects/decoded-gnu-coreutils/chroot.html). The only difference is that, before doing all that stuff, it [tweaks a bit of internal state in the process table](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chroot.2.html) so that whenever some code in the new process tries to read the path `/`, the kernel will "lie" to it by giving the content of `/newroot` instead of the content of `/`. And since every absolute path lookup on a Linux system starts by reading `/` and stepping down a directory at a time from there, that means the new process will only ever find things under `/newroot` (aside from some niche edge cases involving relative paths). But other than that, running `chroot` is essentially just running a normal process.

If you wanted to get a startup process like what happens when your Ubuntu system first starts up, you need a lot more than `chroot`. What you would need is something that starts a special init process, which would be responsible for starting all the other system services (logger, scheduled task runner, network manager, graphical display manager, etc.), one of which is the thing that calls `mount -a`. Only after all those system services get started would it then run the thing that you originally wanted it to run, like `/bin/sh`. (And if you did this for real, you would need ways to prevent this new init process from interfering with the one that started Ubuntu itself. You would basically wind up reinventing Docker.)

In your case, depending on what you're trying to do, you may or may not need the full system startup process. If you do, just use Docker or some equivalent - that's what containers are made for. But if you don't, you can probably get away with a wrapper script which will mount everything you need to mount and then start the shell or whatever you want. Your wrapper script could be as simple as this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

mount -a
exec "$@"
```

and if you save it as `/newroot/usr/local/sbin/mount-and-run`, you could use it like this:

```
chroot /newroot /usr/local/sbin/mount-and-run /bin/sh
```

which will run `chroot`, which in turn will invoke `mount-and-run`, which will do the mounts and then in turn invoke `/bin/sh`. (If you want to unmount things before `mount-and-run` exits, then that gets a little more complicated, but that'd be a matter for a different question.)